# Div box shadow only in 2 side?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How i get the box shadow like the following site?

http://literacy2030.org/

The joinUs,find allis, Get support box.

Comment: That's an image. You can't create that kind of shadows with css only.

Comment: @Kees not true, you can, however it requires thought and css knowledge.

Comment: Ah just saw the answer below. Awesome. did not know that :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this css :

```
.shadow:before, .shadow:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.shadow:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

[Sources here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css_box_shadow/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty comprehensive list of CSS3 box shadow effects:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

For what you want – **lifted corners**, you will need to create **pseudo before** and **after** elements, apply a `box-shadow` to them and **rotate** them using the `transform` property at reflecting angles.

For example:

```
/* Standard box-shadow applied to element */
.lifted-corners {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
/* Rotated box-shadow applied to before and after pseudo elements */
.lifted-corners:before,
.lifted-corners:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
/* Reflected position and rotation for the pseudo after element */
.lifted-corners:after {
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

...you will of course have to prefix the `box-shadow` and `transform` properties for your target browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by inspecting the respective element in your developer console, this is a background image: http://literacy2030.org/wp-content/themes/literacy_base_v0.6/img/main_boxes_home.png

You cannot achieve this kind of effect without using an image in CSS (or maybe you can, but it is really not worth the trouble).

Comment: That is not exactly true, it's possible without images. It's a bit tricky though. (You have to use pseudo-elements and some rotation magic insteads). Edit: see [Cana's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17020773/1047823).

Comment: Read my answer carefully ! It says you **can** but it is not worth the trouble (imo). Cana's answer is an interesting alternative, but the result are nowhere near as elegant as the background-image - and I don't really see the reason for not using the image.

Comment: I find it far more difficult to create such an image than putting together a simple pseudoelement declaration with rotate+boxshadow. I really see no reason for using an image;) Also you added this additional sentence after I wrote my comment (at least I didn't see it in the beginning).

Comment: @Christoph: That is very nice ! Different people, different skillsets, different techniques: everyone uses what best fits their requirements and everyone is happy. I think both solutions are valid and it is normal (and positive) to have more than one ways to address a particular problem.

Comment: I agree on the your statement. Have a nice day;)